# Making a vector field divergence-free

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I have a feeling that this is not true, but I'm not sure how to construct a counter-example.

Given a non-vanishing smooth vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a positive smooth function $f$ such that the re-scaled vector field $fX$ is divergence-free?

This involves solving the following PDE for $f$, with coefficients depending on $X$ and its first derivatives:
$$df(X) + f\text{div}(X) = 0.$$

Comment: I think you'll want to make $X$ at least differentiable, maybe smooth.

Comment: I did mean smooth, whoops.

Comment: I think you can use the method of characteristics to show that we have a solution whenever $\frac{divX}{X}$ is $C^1$. That would imply that the corresponding system of ODEs has a solution. My only hang up is showing that we then have a positive solution--just thinking about how general solutions for PDEs tend to look, my gut tells me there would be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recipe for a counterexample in at three dimensions. We can start with a general one which is not nonvanishing:

Let $U(x)=x^ie_i$, where $e_i$ are the standard tangent frame in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Integrating around a ball $B(0,r)$ centered at the origin of radius $r$, we can apply the divergence theorem:
$$
\int_{B(0,r)}\text{div}(fU)dV=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}fU\cdot n\ ds=r\int_{\partial B(0,r)}f\ ds>0
$$
The same type of argument applies to any vector field $V$ for which there exists a closed hypersurface $S$ with normal $n$ such that $V\cdot n\neq 0$ in all of $S$.

In the above example, it's not possible to remove the zero in the interior of the sphere. However, the same general approach is useful in a more complicated case for $\mathbb{R}^3$:

Let $T$ be a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ about the $z$-axis with a circle $C$ in its interior on the $xy$-plane. One can construct a rotationally symmetric vector field $U$ which points radially outward on all of $T$, and has zeros only on $C$ and on the $z$-axis. Using bump functions, both of these zeros can be removed with localized fields.

This approach won't work in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it generalize pretty straightforwardly to higher dimensions It's not at all clear to me what vector fields *do* satisfy the condition, though it seems to be a very restricted set.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because the OP asked for a non-vanishing smooth vector field, but your proposed vector field vanishes at the origin. Though my intuition tells me it is possible to modify the behaviour of the function near the origin, by using suitable bump functions

Comment: My mistake for missing the non-vanishing condition. I don't think a modification is possible, though: the presence of a zero is topologically required.

Comment: +1. I think, if $fX$ is also parallel then the underlying topology must have $b_1\geq 1$ while $b_1(\Bbb R^{n\geq 2})=0$.

Comment: More specifically, the modification is topologically forbidden if the surface is spherical. It seems to work for a torus.

Comment: I know this is getting slightly off topic, but what topological restriction is preventing us from removing the zero at the origin in the first example? (just relevant references/buzzwords will suffice, no need for a full explanantion)

Comment: I think it's a consequence of the Brouwer fixed point theorem, among others: for a nonvanishing outward-pointing in vector field $V$ on the closed unit ball $B$, $-V/\|V\|$ is a smooth map $B\to B$ with no fixed points.

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice example.